# access denied when connecting commands

Tags: java, powershell, cmd

I want to connect multiple commands into one string but i'm having an issue:

If I run the following commands in CMD seperately, it works:

```
powershell.exe
pushd path_to_active_UNC_directory
$Env:PRESTO_PASSWORD=XXXXX 
java -jar presto.jar --server https://address.of.server --catalog hive --debug --schema murex_tradestore --user=test --password --execute "SELECT * FROM TABLE;" --output-format CSV_HEADER > test.csv
popd
```

However, if i connect the commands, it only works up until `$Env:PRESTO_PASSWORD=XXXXX`

if I add `java -jar presto.jar --server https://address.of.server --catalog hive --debug --schema murex_tradestore --user=test --password --execute "SELECT * FROM TABLE;" --output-format CSV_HEADER > test.csv` then it errors out with 'access denied'

What could be the reason of this? given that it does work when I run the commands after each other. Below the code that I run when I connect the commands:

```
powershell.exe; pushd path_to_active_UNC_directory;$Env:PRESTO_PASSWORD=XXXXX; java -jar presto.jar --server https://address.of.server --catalog hive --debug --schema murex_tradestore --user=test --password --execute "SELECT * FROM TABLE;" --output-format CSV_HEADER > test.csv;popd
```

Comment: I would guess that in order for it not to deny access, you'd need to provide a password!

Comment: that's what `$Env:PRESTO_PASSWORD=XXXXX`  is for. You can set the PRESTO_PASSWORD environment variable with the password value to avoid the prompt

Comment: The point I was making is that you're defining an environment variable, but then running a `java` command which doesn't use it and a `pop-location` command which also doesn't use it! What is using that password?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works. But if I set `$Env:PRESTO_PASSWORD=XXX` it is being picked up when I run it line by line. 

PRESTO_PASSWORD environment var is the way to go according to the docs. https://docs.starburst.io/350-e/installation/cli.html

Comment: I know how an environment variable works! What I'm telling you is that from what you've posted there is no indication whatsoever that anything is using that password, you haven't provided us with sufficient information! In order for us to assist you, you are supposed to submit a [mcve] of your code, and sufficient information for us to replicate your reported issue.

Comment: @eureka, `--password` is in the java command line. Is there supposed to be a value for password on the command line? Or, is it expected that the code in presto.jar get it from the inherited environment?

Comment: @lit it inherits it from the environment. I solved the issue by running a seperate ps1 file. then it does seem to work

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the issue by creating a powershell script (ps1) and running the script. In that way i didn't need to "connect" the different commands.

Now it seems to pickup the password.

code:

```
powershell.exe; Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass; #path_to_ps1 -path $path -usr_pass $usr_pass -usr_name $usr_name -sql_code $sql_code -file_name $file_name -schema $schema
```

code cl1:

```
param([string] $path = "C:\",
      [string] $usr_pass = "",
      [string] $usr_name = "",
      [string] $sql_code = "",
      [string] $file_name = "",
      [string] $schema = ""
)

pushd $path
$Env:PRESTO_PASSWORD=$usr_pass
java -jar presto.jar --server https://presto-poc.dap.pl.ing.net --catalog hive --debug --schema $schema --user=$usr_name --password --execute "$sql_code;" --output-format CSV_HEADER > $file_name
popd
```